# Сломалась сборка через gcc

Tags: linux, c, gcc, компоновщик

Появляется сообщение об ошибке при компиляции

```
$ gcc test.c
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o: нераспознанное перемещение (0x2a) в разделе «.init»
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Некорректное значение
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Описание бага есть на [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1575109)

Переустановка пакетов `gcc`, `libc-dev`, `binutils`, `build-essential` результатов не дала.

Система Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa 64-bit

Comment: А раньше все собиралось? make clean попробуйте.

Comment: Раньше да. Теперь компиляция даже простого кода на Си `$ gcc *.c` выдает такую ошибку.

Comment: А что было между "работало" и "перестало"? Я так понимаю даже простейший hello world теперь не собирается?

Comment: Именно, даже hello world. Вероятно что-то поломалось после установки обновлений, но определить какой именно пакет ответственен за это безобразие пока не получается. "Перестало" еще на Mint 17.2 Rafaela, после обновления до 17.3 проблема не исчезла. Возможно также влияние установленного Matlab R2016a, который использует старую библиотеки `libstdc++.so.6`, в отличие от поставляемой с минтом. Ради совместимости все было сделано по [инструкции](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=70607947#70607947). В результате Matlab работает, gcc - нет.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал для сборки и компиляции юзать отдельную виртуалку со снимком состояния, в котором 100% всё работает. Немного геморно в начале, но потом спасёт вот от такой фигни.

Comment: Поддерживаю комментарий про виртуалку. Только лучше не готовый снимок хранить (есть риск потерять или перезаписать), а код воспроизведения конфигурации. Можно shell-скриптом (`apt-get install a b c`), можно инструкциями для системы управления конфигурациями вроде ansible/puppet/chef/saltstack. Версии всех используемых пакетов должны быть заморожены (т.е. указаны явно и меняться сознательно и под контролем).

Comment: `Возможно также влияние установленного Matlab R2016a` - это ещё одна причина собирать на чистой виртуалке.

Comment: Спасибо за совет про чистую виртуалку - там (Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr) все собирается. Просто у кого-то [проблема](https://lists.debian.org/debian-russian/2015/12/msg00112.html) [решается](https://debianforum.ru/index.php?topic=10402.0) установкой обновлений. До определенного момента и gcc, и Matlab работали параллельно и друг другу не мешали. Последний, правда, только через терминал запускался.

Comment: А вы симлинки прямо в /usr/lib обновили?

Answer (score 1):

Можно обратить внимание на два момента:

> ld returned 1 exit status

Т.е. падает не GCC вовсе, а линкер.
И линкер говорит, что проблема возникает при линкове .init:

> нераспознанное перемещение (0x2a) в разделе «.init»

Насколько я понимаю ситуацию, такой "ужас" может возникнуть только из-за того, что линкер "не понимает" формат объектного файла, содержащего секцию ".init". Ну, или там вообще, что-то совершенно из другой оперы.

Первое, что приходит в голову - вы получаете объектник для одной платформы (скажем - ARM), а линкер пытается собрать модуль для х86. Ну и происходит нестыковка форматов.

Или, может, аппаратная платформа одна, но ОС - разные...

Могли Вы где-то переписать необходимую библиотеку "чужой" ?

Comment: До создания объектного файла дело даже не доходит, поэтому сложно сказать кто виноват. Заменена только `libstdc++.so.6`, gcc ее вроде бы не использует. Как узнать, что библиотека "чужая"?

Comment: **Как узнать, что библиотека "чужая"? **. Есть много способов...
1) В mc подвести курсор к библиотеке и нажать F3. В верхней строке будет текст вроде "ELF 32-bit MSB  shared object, PowerPC". Это и есть описание платформы.

Comment: 2) Можно использовать команду file <имя файла библиотеки> Результат будет тот же самый.

Comment: 3) Кучу всякой информации можно получить с помощью objdump -f <имя объектного файла>

Comment: Кстати говоря, полный список используемых ELF-ом библиотек можно получить с помощью команды: ldd <Имя исполняемого(ELF) файла>

Comment: mc дает такую информацию: "ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64".
ldd такую

 `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffecbf83000)`

 `libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7b67203000)`

 `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7b675ee000)`

Comment: **ldd такую** Вот теперь проверьте (хотя бы с помощью mc) все пречесленные ldd библиотеки на соответствие "ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64"

Comment: `libc.so.6` оказалась симлинком на `libc-2.23.so`, которая "ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64" и располагается по тому же адресу.
`ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` - симлинк на `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so`, которая также "ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64".
Библиотека `linux-vdso.so.1` размещается только в адресном пространстве отдельной программы.

Comment: Похоже, здесь всё нормально... Последняя гипотеза: может быть Вы, при сборке Вашей программы используете свою собственную библиотеку (.so), которую собрали без флага -fPIC ?